# UserControls using the same events

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm making Windows 10 UWP app.
To make it simple, let's say I have a *TextBox* somewhere on my page. Under this *TextBox* there are my 3 (different types) custom controls. These 3 controls have the same property and event that is raised if user clicks a button inside one of these controls, and the method to which this event is subscribed to causes that the text inside a *TextBox* is assigned to *SomeProperty* in the control.

Is there some way to subscribe to these events, so that I don't have to have 3 different methods handling it while they're literally doing the same thing, but for 3 different controls.

This is the code that all of the controls have in common. There are MyControlA, MyControlB and MyControlC

```
public sealed partial class MyControlA : UserControl
{
    public delegate void StartPositionClickedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event StartPositionClickedEventHandler StartPositionClicked;

    public string SomeProperty
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SomePropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SomePropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    private void StartPosition_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StartPositionClicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SomeProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomePropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SomeProperty", typeof(string), typeof(MyControlA), null);
}
```

I subscribe to the event in the page where the control is

```
_control.StartPositionClicked += new MyControlA.StartPositionClickedEventHandler(SetCurrentStartPositon);
```

and handle it

```
private void SetCurrentStartPositon(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _control.SomeProperty = DummyTextBox.Text;
}
```

And I would have to do that for all of the controls, but I might have lots of them as they're created programmatically as they're needed, so I wish to have some better way of doing it. Everything I thought of seems to be dumb or super inefficient.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all your controls have the same properties of the same type, there are two ways how to achieve what you want:

**1: Creating a base class** that will implement the code they all have in common and make all the controls inherit from it:

```
public abstract class MyControlBase : UserControl
{
    public delegate void StartPositionClickedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event StartPositionClickedEventHandler StartPositionClicked;

    public string SomeProperty
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SomePropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SomePropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    protected void StartPosition_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StartPositionClicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SomeProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomePropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SomeProperty", typeof(string), typeof(MyControlA), null);
}

public sealed partial class MyControlA : MyControlBase
{
    // Class specific code
}
```

Please note that you'll also need to change the base class in XAML so instead of something like

```
<UserControl>
    <!-- Your XAML code -->
</UserControl>
```

you have to use something like this assuming `xmlns:local` points to the namespace in which `MyControlBase` is:

```
<local:MyControlBase>
    <!-- Your XAML code -->
</local:MyControlBase>
```

Then you can make one event handler that will look similar to this:

```
private void SetCurrentStartPositon(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the control that invoked this event
    MyControlBase senderControl = (MyControlBase)sender;
    senderControl.SomeProperty  = DummyTextBox.Text;
}
```

**2: Creating a simple interface** for them like this and make all the three controls inherit from it:

```
public interface IMyControl
{
    string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

So in your code, you could subscribe events of all the controls to one method that will look like this one:

```
private void SetCurrentStartPositon(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the control that invoked this event
    IMyControl senderControl   = (IMyControl)sender;
    senderControl.SomeProperty = DummyTextBox.Text;
}
```

I'd suggest using the first option since it makes your code simplier to read and avoids possible inconsistencies from changing the common code.

Comment: I was trying to do something similar though I didn't write <local:MyControlBase> and I had, and I still have lots of strange errors given by Visual Studio but cleaning solution and temp. files helped, though they were very missleading and not that easy to remove. Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can!
It is called `EventSetter` and you can use it like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControlA}">
    <EventSetter Event="StartPositionClicked" Handler="SomeAction"/>
</Style>
```

You need to put this style in the parent control i.e. `Grid` or `StackPanel` and also you need to implement the `SomeAction` method.
HTH

Comment: From what I can see there is type that you have to set. In this case it's MyControlA. But I have also MyControlB and C etc. that are different types.

Comment: @MichalKania in this case you have to create different styles, but you can still use the same event. I have done the same only one week ago.

Comment: You didn't specify that in your question, but as @MarkusDeibel said, just add style per type.

Comment: Also isn't it for WPF? I guess I omitted few important things so I'll update the question. Also these controls are created programmatically that is actually already in the question ;)

Comment: @MichalKania I have noticed you changed the tags, and when I said "_You didn't specify that in your question_" I meant the different types, I thought you had multiple instances of `MyControlA` like in a `ListView`.